# C++ Struct Default Call Value

Tags: c++, struct

New to C++ here. Lets say I have a struct defined as:

```
struct Item {
  string name;
}
```

In C++, is there a way where I can get the value of `name` by just calling the object?

```
Item item;
item.name = "Andy"
cout << item; // --> Output: "Andy"
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can overload `<<` to do the job for you. `std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & out, const Item & item) { out << item.name;  return out; }`. What that means and more wisdom here: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overload the stream insertion operator `operator<<` for `Item` type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Item {
  std::string name;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Item& obj);
};
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Item& obj) {
    // Feel free to extend this function to print what you like.
    // You can even do something like 'stream << "Item(" << obj.name << ")";'.
    // The implementation is upto you as long as you return the stream object.
    stream << obj.name;
    return stream;
  }

int main() {
  Item it{"Item1"};
  std::cout << it << std::endl;
}
```

[Try it out yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/BuBWWt)

More references on the topic:

[reference 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=vs-2019)

[reference 2](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/)

Comment: Side note: `struct`s generally don't have much use for `friend`s. They default to `public` access, so unless you add restrictions, they are `friend`ly to everyone.

Comment: @user4581301 True, I just wanted to make the solution more general. In the case of public visibility to data members it makes no difference

Comment: No worries. That's why I left it as a note for the self-professed C++ newbie and not a snarkfest.